# R: Parsing boolean command line argument in using argparse

Tags: r, argparse

I am using "argparse" library in R for command line arguments.

```
# Create parser
parser = ArgumentParser(description='command line args')

# Add command line arguments

parser$add_argument("is_local", nargs='?', type="logical", 
                    help="whether to use local or server path", default=FALSE)

parser$add_argument("alert", nargs='?', type="double",
                    help="alert threshold", default=0.99)
```

I am trying to call it on command line such as:

`Rscript my_func.R TRUE 0.99`

However boolean argument does not change. Any idea how to parse boolean argument in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `R`, but the description of this package says it's a wrapper for the Python `argparse`.

I would recommend changing these:

```
parser$add_argument("is_local", nargs='?', type="logical", 
                    help="whether to use local or server path", default=FALSE)    
parser$add_argument("alert", nargs='?', type="double",
                    help="alert threshold", default=0.99)
```

to

```
parser$add_argument("--local", action='store_true'), 
                    help="whether to use local or server path")
parser$add_argument("--alert", type="double",
                    help="alert threshold", default=0.99)
```

which would be called with

```
Rscript my_func.R --local --alert 0.99
```

`store_true` is illustrated on the basic docs page, https://github.com/trevorld/r-argparse

If I read the `R` correctly, your `is_local` should be giving you a warning

> "You almost certainly want to use action='store_true' or action='store_false' instead"

A `store_true` argument sets the attribute to `TRUE` if present, and the default `FALSE` if absent.  It should be an `optional` (--) and not set the `nargs`.

(It is possible to have an argument that takes strings 'true' and 'false' (or any other pair in your native language) and converts them to logical values, but requires more coding.)

I made `--alert` a flagged argument as well, without the nargs.  Its value will be the default if absent, and the convert the string to a `double` if provided.  It could be a '?' positional, but while learning I think it's best to stick with `optionals` unless you want the argument to be required.

The `R-argparse` docs aren't very complete.  You may need to refer to the Python docs, and experiment to get the translation right.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and help!

I would like to share my workaround for the problem as I find original argparse (action) usage a bit complicated.

```
# Convert str input to boolean
str2bool = function(input_str)
{
  if(input_str == "0")
  {
    input_str = FALSE
  } 
  else if(input_str == "1")
  {
    input_str = TRUE
  }
  return(input_str)
}

# Create parser
parser = ArgumentParser(description='command line args')

# Add command line arguments

parser$add_argument("is_local",  nargs='?', type="character",
                    help="whether to use local or server path", default="1")

parser$add_argument("alert", nargs='?', type="double",
                    help="alert threshold", default=0.99)

# Parse arguments
args = parser$parse_args()

# Convert str arguments 
args$is_local = str2bool(args$is_local)

# Call on CMD line
Rscript my_func.R 1 0.99     #equivalent Rscript my_func.R TRUE 0.99
Rscript my_func.R 0 0.99     #equivalent Rscript my_func.R FALSE 0.99
```

Comment: note that `input_str <- as.logical(input_str)` is a shorter replacement for `str2bool`.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the sample example given in the official docs of package `argparse`:

```
parser <- ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers')
parser$add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type="integer", nargs='+',
help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser$add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
const='sum', default='max',
help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
parser$print_help()

# default args for ArgumentParser()$parse_args are commandArgs(TRUE)
# which is what you'd want for an Rscript but not for interactive use

args <- parser$parse_args(c("--sum", "1", "2", "3"))
accumulate_fn <- get(args$accumulate)
print(accumulate_fn(args$integers))
```

Here is the link for the `argparse` pdf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/argparse.pdf

I hope it might help.

Comment: Please avoid posting answers that are not directly addressing questions. I came across 4 answers from you today (by accident, as I was answering questions in r tag), and only one of them was actually answering the questions. The others were mostly general ideas, using different data than the OP's sample data or just some code which won't make the desired output. Good practice would be including the output in your answers (not for this one that is copied from documentation). If it matches the desired output, you are good; otherwise, your answer needs revision before getting posted here. Cheers.

Comment: As a side note. I am not requiring you to do so. I have no authority to ask or demand. This is a friendly advice to improve quality of your posts.